# Twitter Sign in with twitteroatuh

Tags: php, authentication, typo3

i want to implement a "sign in with twitter" as optional "registration", like Facebook. I have found the twitteroauth and tested a little bit. The problem is, i do not have any idea, how can i use this library in my extension (typo3) controller, to make all calls.

```
require "typo3conf/ext/mbx_twitter/Classes/Controller/autoload.php";
```

class TwitterController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

```
public function loginAction() {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    if(isset($this->settings['consumerKey']) && isset($this->settings['consumerSecret'])) {

        $consumerKey = $this->settings['consumerKey'];
        $consumerSecret = $this->settings['consumerSecret'];
        $callback = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];


        $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => "nMznkpFRTMCuNMsmALzel9FgPlmWQDWg"));

    }

    $this->view->assign('', '');
}
```

}

This code don`t work and i found only old examples. Do you have any idea, how can i realize the twitter login with this library? The App and the consumer keys are generated.

Best regards 
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the extension `openid` provided with the core. Providing an authentication service that also creates user accounts is not an easy task. You should consider hiring a professional for the security related code.